# Return my S4 Mini 4.2.2 Jelly Bean to stock firmware

Tags: rom, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I want to return my S4 mini 4.2.2 Jelly Bean to stock firmware, but can't find the specific ROM for baseband version I919XXUAMDE/ build numbber JDQ39.I9190XXUAMDE. You could help me a lot if you told me the way to install it - I want to install it from cell phone because I can't use USB cable.

Technical details:

```
Model nr : GT-I9190
Android version  -  4.2.2 // Kernel Version : 3.4.5 whl@server0-br#1 
Software version -- V86.08  
baseband version I919XXUAMDE 
build numbber JDQ39.I9190XXUAMDE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do manage to find it, to install it you'll need to download it to your phone, boot into recovery, make a backup, wipe your /system, /data, /cache, and dalvik cache (NOT internal Memory or your SD card if you have one) then flash the file you downloaded.

Comment: But the problem is that I CAN'T find the appropriate stock ROM for my S4 mini ! ! !   That's why I need your help. - You could tell me where to find it.

Comment: Can I use a stock rom of a similar baseband version???